# When in ~ directory, why doesn't ls show /usr/ directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, ls

I can `cd /usr/`, but why doesn't `ls -a` or `ls -d` or `ls -d */` show me that the `usr` directory is there?

I have already seen this question, but `ls -d */` yields ls: `cannot access */: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would see the `usr` directory if your current directory is `/`. Your home directory, abbreviated as `~`, is probably not the root directory but something like `/home/adam`.

When you call `cd /usr`, you’re using an absolute path, as indicated by the leading slash. This call behaves the same wherever you execute it from.

When you call `cd usr`, you tell `cd` to change into the `usr` directory that is in the current working directory. Because it’s relative, it behaves differently for every directory.

`ls -a` (and friends) without further arguments (or arguments lacking a leading slash) also work relative to the current working directory.

You can see your current working directory’s full path with the `pwd` command.